# Drag and Drop with Snap in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

this is my first post! I have created a GUI in tkinter with three entry boxes, this then  creates a label that can then be dragged and dropped onto my map in the next frame.  I am looking at snapping the location, is this possible?

This is an extract of my code:

```
vehicle_1=Entry(my_frame3,width=5)
vehicle_1.place(x=150,y=100)
Vehicle1_Label = Label(my_frame3,text="Enter Vehicle 1 Number:")
Vehicle1_Label.place(x=15,y=100)

vehicle_2=Entry(my_frame3,width=5)
vehicle_2.place(x=150,y=150)
Vehicle2_Label = Label(my_frame3,text="Enter Vehicle 2 Number:")
Vehicle2_Label.place(x=15,y=150)

vehicle_3=Entry(my_frame3,width=5)
vehicle_3.place(x=150,y=200)
Vehicle3_Label = Label(my_frame3,text="Enter Vehicle 3 Number:")
Vehicle3_Label.place(x=15,y=200)

def open1():

    def drag_start(event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.startX = event.x
        widget.startY = event.y

    def drag_motion(event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
        widget.place(x=x,y=y)

    global ConsistLabelVar
    if ConsistLabelVar == 0: 
        Consist_Label = Label(my_frame2,text=vehicle_1.get()+"              "+vehicle_2.get()+"              "+vehicle_3.get())
        Consist_Label.place(x=250,y=0)
        Consist_Label.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
        Consist_Label.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)
```

Comment: Try changing `widget.place(x=x,y=y)` to `widget.place(x=x//50*50, y=y//50*50)`. That should snap it to a grid of `50x50` pixels.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks!  Do you know how you could snap it to a certain area?  Like assigning cars in a car park for example?

Comment: Look at what I did: `var//50*50`, it rounds `var` to the nearest `50` pixels by dividing by 50 (and getting rid of the remainder) then multiplying by 50. You can do something similar in your code. Round `x` to the nearest `width_of_parking_space`. If you give me more details like where do the parking spaces start is it `(0, 0)`, how big is a parking space, I should be able to give you a solution

Comment: I think I can do it from the info you have given me thanks!  I will just change the image to suit the snapping, so they are all 50 by 50 and 50 apart.

Comment: How would you get the coordinates so it could be stored in a database?

Comment: Use `<widget>.place_info()`. It returns a dictionary like this: `{'in': <tkinter.Tk object .>, 'x': '0', 'relx': '0', 'y': '0', ...}`. So you can use `place_kwargs = <widget>.place_info()` and then `x = place_kwargs["x"]` and `y = place_kwargs["y"]`

Comment: So I have been printing by x and y coordinates.  But it doesn't seem to account for the snap? It just prints where my mouse it